# Database connection pointing to wrong database

Tags: database, eclipse, web-applications, glassfish

I have a web project in eclipse using glassfish. I have the following datasource entries in context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/TestDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:db1"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" username="test" password="test" />
</Context>
```

When I run my application

```
DatabaseMetaData dmd = connection.getMetaData();
 String name = dmd.getDatabaseProductName();
```

Database product name is always `Apache Derby`

What could be the reason for this? I am trying to connect to Oracle Database however connection is made to Apache Derby.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

*Update 1*

```
public static DatabaseConnection getInstance(String name)
            throws DatabaseException {

        DatabaseConnection instance;
        DataSource ds;
        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            ds = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/"
                    + name);


        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new DatabaseException("###data source is invalid ###" + e);

        }
        instance = new MYDataSource(ds);

        return instance;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that gets you the Database connection?

Comment: @CarlosGavidia I have added my database connection part as update 1 above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.

I created a a JDBC Resource under GlassFish and pointed connection to my connection created under Date Source Explorer. It created a `sun-resources.xml`. I had to manually rename this to `glassfish-resource.xml`. By default there are no entry for password,so I had to manually add `<property name="Passwrod" value="password" />`. When I ran my web application I was getting this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: No PasswordCredential found
```

So to resolve this error I added a property in JDBC Connection Pool in glassfish admin server. Now I could connect to Oracle database.

Not sure why I have to do two steps manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

seems as if you are mixing some stuff up here. context.xml obviously is a Apache Tomcat configuration file. In GlassFish you need to either use the glassfish-resources.xml or configure your domain directly via either the admin GUI or the domain.xml.
There is a basic example of how to do this with GlassFish 3.1 in the GlassFish docs:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggndx.html

Have fun!
Markus